# Variable sent as parameter changes value in parent function

Tags: javascript

Lately i have encountered a weird issue.
I know there was in C++ a way to send variables as a parameter to a function and have them changed by the called function without having to return it.

Well in JS i knew that would not be possible unless the variable its global.
However it does. In some tests I have made this should not be a thing, but with my code in particular this happens.

```js
const setState = (boatShore, boat, state) => {
    // this shit should not perform a transition
    console.log(JSON.stringify(state))
    var valid = validateTransition(boatShore, boat, state)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(state)) // the state here is different from the state at line 3.
    console.log('\n');

    boat = [];
    boatShore = boatShore === 0 ? 1 : 0;
    return { boatShore, boat, state, valid };
}

// this indeed changes the state in its runtime but it should not affect the caller
function validateTransition(boatShore, boat, state) {
    if (boat.length > 2 || boat.length < 1) { return false }
    for (let individual of boat) {
        if (boatShore !== state[individual.pairIndex][individual.index]) return false;   
    }
    state = transitionState(boat,state)
    for (let pair of state) {
        if (pair[0] !== pair[1]) {
            for (let pairCheck of state) {
                if (pairCheck[0] === pair[1]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function transitionState(boat,state) {
    for (let individual of boat) {
        if (state[individual.pairIndex][individual.index] === 0) {
            state[individual.pairIndex][individual.index] = 1;
        } else {
            state[individual.pairIndex][individual.index] = 0;
        }
    }
    return state;
}

problem(4);
function problem(n){
    var state = []; //[[0,0], [0,0], [0,0], [0,0]]
    var boat = []; //[{ pairIndex: 0, index: 0 },{ pairIndex: 0, index:1 }]
    var boatShore = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      state.push([0, 0]);
    }
    setState(boatShore, [{ pairIndex: 0, index: 0 },{ pairIndex: 0, index:1 }], state)
}
```

Here I have a function that should be able to change the "state" variable.
For validation i made a separate function that troughout its checks has to check the modified state also.
Inside the setState i ran only the function to validate the transition and i did not perform any actual changes to the state. Yet the value of state at line 3 is different compared to the state at line 5, so I must say I am quite confused.

Is there any way to prevent this ?
Also why is this happening ?

Comment: JS passes objects by reference. In your function you are already mutating state at the line `state = transitionState(boat,state)`

Comment: `validateState` calls `transitionState` which does `state[individual.pairIndex][individual.index] = 1;` or `state[individual.pairIndex][individual.index] = 0;`. Objects are reference values in JavaScript and they are mutable, i.e. any change made to a particular object anywhere can be observed wherever there is a reference to that object.

Comment: @Terry: Not *by* reference, **as** reference. "By reference" is something different: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference

Comment: Yes but shouldn't that change only affect the scope of ```validateTransition``` function ? 
The value is also modified in ```setState ``` without any explicit definitions of the state.

Comment: Here is a simple example of mutable object references: `function foo(x) { x.hello = 'world'; }; var obj = {}; foo(obj); console.log(obj);`.

Comment: @IonutEugen: No. As I said, objects are mutable reference values. When you pass an object to a function you are passing a reference to that object, not a copy of the object. And because objects are mutable, the function can make changes to that object.

Comment: I’m pretty sure it’s pass “by” reference. Never seen it named as “pass AS reference” anywhere before. https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-pass-by-value/ https://dev.to/bytebodger/a-gotcha-of-javascript-s-pass-by-reference-1afm

Comment: Ok, i think i get it. Is there an instance in which i can pass an object as an immutable reference ?
One thing Im thinking of is to pass the object as a string and parse it inside my function. Although that seems like uite a forceful workaround .

Comment: [pass by reference](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+(%22pass+as+reference%22+OR+%22pass+by+reference%22))